# Web page not displayed when using <Iframe> tag in HTML

Tags: html, iframe

The web page is not displayed when the following was inserted in the html. Neither was this working for any other link. Please tell me what is the problem in this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Iframes</h2>
<p>You can also use the CSS height and width properties to specify the size of the iframe:</p>

<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com"  style="height:500px;width:900px"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the console:

> Refused to display 'https://www.w3schools.com/' in a frame because it
>   set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

This means that W3 Schools will not allow you to [display its pages in an external iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).

Comment: Hey! Thanks. It worked when I entered a youtube Video Link.

Answer (score 0):

No need to have the style attribute.

```
<iframe height="500px" width="800px" src="https://www.google.com" ></iframe>
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Try
    <iframe height="your height " width="your width" src="your link"></iframe>
fixed above answer to show complete answer.

Comment: Are you using a style sheet?